# How does one soften sun dried tomatoes?

Tags: tomatoes

Some packs of sun dried tomatoes come a bit too hard to chew.  How do I soften them for use in a salad?  Should I toss them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally you soak them in a small amount of very hot water for about 10 minutes or until they are as soft as you want them. The flavorful liquid that comes out of that process can be used in salad dressings, soups, sauces, etc. (A quick way to do this is throw them in a microwave safe bowl with water to cover and microwave for say 3 minutes, then allow to stand.)

Answer (score 3):

Steaming works.